# cannot load settings file with .groovy extension into gremlin console

Tags: database, gremlin, tinkerpop3

In order to get my console set up and running to work with graphs in gremlin, I need to load a settings configuration file into the gremlin console.

However, no matter what I try(e.g.change the directory of the tinker pop folder/change location of the config file), it outputs "File not found" error, even when I specify the absolute file path:

```
command:
:load filepath_on_my_pc\load-air-routes.groovy

output:
File not found: "filepath_on_my_pc\load-air-routes.groovy"
```

Thanks in advance, I think I am overlooking something really simple haha.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac/Linux ? If the file is in the same directory as the place where you launched the console just `:load load-air-routes.groovy` should work. How are you specifying the path?

Comment: You should just be able to do `gremlin> :load c:\path\file.groovy` then. Try putting them one level above `gremlin.bat` if you want to not use a path.

Comment: I am writing on windows 10. And yes, the files downloaded are in the same directory as gremlin.bat file to launch the console.  ((..\Documents\Programming\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.6.1-bin\bin))                                                                   
Before that, I loaded and tried launching the settings file from the directory containing all the gremlin files located (..\Documents\Programming\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.6.1-bin) where I created a separate folder for them.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine all you should need to do is

```
gremlin> :load c:\path\file.groovy
```

If you do not want to specify a path the file needs to be in the same location as the root directory for the gremlin console (not in the `\bin` folder). In that case you can just do:

```
gremlin> :load file.groovy
```

`